# Mediation and CustomEventBanner java

Tags: java, admob

I would like to create a CustomEventBanner but have some questions. Im not sure if I do the right things at the right place. Where should I add the Banner to my layout? Do I have to call every method of the CustomEventBannerListener? Which are those which are absolutly necessary? How do I know if there is no Ad to display (no anouncer)??

I actually can display Ad with admob but not using my CustomAd :(

Here is my code:

```
public class CustomAd implements CustomEventBanner, AdResponseHandler {
private CustomEventBannerListener bannerListener;
protected SASBannerView mBannerView;

@Override
public void requestBannerAd(final CustomEventBannerListener listener,
        final Activity activity, String label, String serverParameter,
        AdSize adSize, MediationAdRequest mediationAdRequest, Object extra) {
    // Keep the custom event listener for use later.
    this.bannerListener = listener;
    // Determine the best ad format to use given the adSize. If the adSize
    // isn't appropriate for any format, an ad will not fill.
    // Create banner instance
    mBannerView = new SASBannerView(activity);

    // Set the listener to register for events.
    this.mBannerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
            listener.onClick();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the ad with the ad request giving an AdResponseHandler
    mBannerView.loadAd(42295, "286177", 18008, true, "",  this);
}

@Override
public void destroy() { // The destroy method gets called when the mediation
                        // framework refreshes
    // and removes the custom event. Perform any necessary cleanup here.
    if (this.mBannerView != null) {
        this.mBannerView.onDestroy();
    }
}


@Override
public void adLoadingCompleted(SASAdElement arg0) {
    this.bannerListener.onReceivedAd(this.mBannerView);
}

@Override
public void adLoadingFailed(Exception arg0) {
    this.bannerListener.onFailedToReceiveAd();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks pretty good. Though your banner doesn't seem to be doing anything on click other than notifying `onClick()`. If you're banner ends up hitting an external web browser or the play store, you can also call `onPresentScreen()` and `onLeaveApplication()` in the onClickListener.

Note that this is just the Custom Event component of your app to implement the SAS network. Your main activity still needs to create an AdView (with a mediation ID set up to target your custom event) and load an ad into it.

Only the `onReceivedAd` and `onFailedToReceiveAd` are absolutely necessary for mediation to run. The others are useful so that your main AdView's AdListener can listen for these events.